# Progress circle with spaces between colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve this effect (spaces between the color blue and grey), like in the image attached. Those would be like some margins of other color or no color between the 2 colors.

[image: What I would like to achieve: arcs with spaces in between.]

But currently managed to this (without spaces).

[image: What I have now: arcs with no space in between.]

```js
function loadPieCircle() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('chart'); // get canvas
  for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    var options = {
      percent: el[i].getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
      size: el[i].getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
      lineWidth: el[i].getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
      rotate: el[i].getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-' + i);

    if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
      G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

    el[i].appendChild(canvas);

    ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
    ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

    //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
    var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

    var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
      percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.lineCap = 'square'; // butt, round or square
      ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
      ctx.stroke();
    };

    drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
    drawCircle('#18aace', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
  }
}
loadPieCircle();
```

```css
.chart {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

span.percentage_circle {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 72px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" data-line="25" data-percent="70">
  <span class="percentage_circle" id="percentage_circle-0">
    Module<br>
    <strong>13/20</strong>
  </span>
  <canvas id="canvas-0" class="canvas" height="220" width="220"></canvas>
</div>
```

It can also be found on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqz2pf5n/).

Comment: You could try subtracting a fixed amount from the length of the arc. It'd have to be pretty small like pi/128

Comment: The idea is to draw a "border" around the arc, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dqz2pf5n/3/)

Comment: Not sure where to add the border or substract length of the arc

Comment: anyone, seams it has to do with variable `ctx`

Comment: Are you set on using a Canvas? Or would using SVG be fine too?

Comment: To render ***exactly*** like the image you show is not easy. I think we need a lot of maths power to achieve that exact chart. Notice the ***square*** spaces between the arcs, we can render a similar/nearly perfect shape easily if that ***square*** space is not required, instead the space can be just ***like a small arc***. Here is a simple demo which renders such kind of arc space (not square space) https://jsfiddle.net/dqz2pf5n/4/ You can see that this is just nearly perfect, in some cases it's acceptable.

Comment: @Hopeless This worked well thanks, you should add it as answer.

Comment: @user3467855 I think one of the newly added answers is better, you should check it out and accept it :) When we don't use maths to manually draw, graphics processing (which is integrated as api) may be a better rescue.

Comment: Also the demo I made does not work expectedly for the case of `0` percentage. So the updated version is here https://jsfiddle.net/dqz2pf5n/5/ (as I said this approach is still acceptable in some cases).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution :

- draw both of your arcs, touching each other.
- set the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) of your context to `'destination-out'`
- draw a closed arc, with a bigger radius, over these arcs. (green in following pic)

Thanks to the gCO, the closed arc is now transparent.

[image]

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function circleChart(perc) {
  var gap = 6;
  var rad = 85;
  var center = canvas.height / 2;
  var start = -Math.PI / 2;
  var end = start + Math.PI * (perc / 50);
  ctx.lineWidth = 25;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#555555';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(center, center, rad, start, end, true);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#18aace';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(center, center, rad, start, end);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, rad * 1.5, start, end, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = gap;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}
inp.oninput = function(){circleChart(this.value)};
circleChart(75);
```

```css
body{background: #f3f5f6;}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0.1" max="100" step=".5" value="75" id="inp"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="220" height="220"></canvas>
```

Ps: I'll let you handle the `0` case as an exercise.

Comment: this is interesting, I've known of graphics composite drawing but not thouhgt of canvas being able to do this. BTW here is the adjusted demo to handle the case of 0 and 100 percent https://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/mf5eb89q/ (for the OP).

Comment: @Hopeless, yes compositing is a great thing in 2D canvas. Note that I didn't provided a way for 0 and 100, because I didn't know what behavior OP wanted in these cases (i.e keep the gap or not ?), and because it would have made the example less clear. But in your implementation, you should wrap the gray arc in an `if( <100)` block, otherwise, you'll create some antialiasing artifacts. Here is a modification of your modification, with both the gap, and this fix https://jsfiddle.net/mf5eb89q/1/

Comment: not sure what the difference between that adjusted demo and your original one (I can still see the gaps when the percentage is 0 or 100). And yes, we still don't know that if the gap should exist even when the percentage is 0 or 100.

Comment: even when the antialiasing artifact is not a problem, we still should not draw the gray arc when the percentage is 100. That is just simple and natural, but the demo was just adjusted quickly from your original one. And btw, you should have made it perfect initially - it does not require much effort, doesn't it?

Comment: @Hopeless, no. The point here is to demonstrate how to draw these *spaces* between arcs. So handling edge cases is noise. I am not here to write bullet-proof libraries, but to learn to others how they can do it. Your comment is good for the ones that want da codez without thinking, but it's not what my answers are made of.

Comment: well I have to say that the antialiasing effect in this case is not easy to detect (may be skipped easily), and if looking in the code, the counter-clockwise drawn gray arc can still be made when the start and end angle nearly match (100 percent) - while others may think there should not be any drawn (I was one of those). The adjusted demo I made mainly focuses on disappearing the gap for 0 and 100 percentage. So I did not notice that issue (which should have been noted by you right in your answer). Really I did not make any full implementation, just a little adjusted demo from ***your own***.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've tried so far, hope it helps.

```
function loadPieCircle() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('chart'); // get canvas
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        var options = {
            percent:  el[i].getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
            size: el[i].getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
            lineWidth: el[i].getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
            rotate: el[i].getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-'+i);

        if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

        el[i].appendChild(canvas);

        ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
        ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

        //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
        var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

        var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent, offset = 0) {
            percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
            ctx.beginPath();
            beginAt = offset;
            ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, beginAt, Math.PI * 2 * percent + offset, false);
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineCap = 'butt'; // butt, round or square
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            ctx.stroke();
        };
        drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, (100-options.percent-2)/100, Math.PI*(0.02025*options.percent));
        drawCircle('#18aace', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
   }
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/j2bpfkgd/1/

Comment: Almost, but the right border is shrinking to much when you add lower percentage, same with left one.

Comment: Yes. Tried to get rid of that but couldn't. I think `@Hopeless` has given the correct way to achieve what you want. He/she must post that as the answer.